# Makefile with coqtop -R coqdir

Tags: makefile, coq, ocamlbuild

I have a makefile:

Add the command: `coqtop -R coqdir` I have to give a physical path in my computer, but this directory depends on user directory. (`~/color/trunk/color/devel/gwen Devel and ~/color/trunk/color CoLoR`).

Is there another way to call and combine a program without given the physical path?

```
tmp/rainbow.native: tmp
coqtop -q -R ~/color/trunk/color/devel/gwen Devel -R ~/color/trunk/color CoLoR 
-batch -load-vernac-source extraction.v && 
(cd tmp && ocamlbuild -j 3 rainbow.native)

tmp:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: So given `~/color/trunk/color/devel/gwenDevel`, you want Make to calculate `/usr/lykimq/color/trunk/color/devel/gwenDevel`?

Comment: It is the directory in my computer, but when I change another computer, this path change. And it is not useful when I have to go inside Makefile and change it. I don't know is there any way that I don't need to give such a path like that but be able to call coqtop and combine the file .v

Comment: Is `~/color/trunk/color/devel/gwenDevel` correct on each computer? Is the absolute path (without `~` or `../`) the thing that changes?

Comment: No the path above is not correct with each computer. For example in another computer I have: color-svn/devel/gwen. The absolute path without ~/ or ../ the path is not change.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `$PATH` environment variable is for: you add directories to it where programs you want to be run will be found.  Basically there's no way `make`, or your makefile, can search the entire computer for the `coqtop` program so the person invoking the makefile has to know where it is and inform the makefile.

Usually this is done by the person who knows where the program is, adding the directory containing the program to their `$PATH` environment variable before they invoke `make`.

If you don't want to go that way, then they will need to set a variable on the `make` command line that points to the location: `make DEVEL=$HOME/color/trunk/color/devel` or similar.  Or they can set the path in an environment variable (`make` always imports all environment variables as makefile macros).

As another option, you can use (assuming you're using GNU make or a make that supports it) `-include local.mk` then have them create a file `local.mk` in their directory that sets this variable before they run `make`; this way they can create that file with the proper path one time and be done with it.

These are about your only options, unless there is some way you can algorithmically determine the path you want based on, for example, the current directory or the directory containing the makefile (which you seem to be saying there isn't).

Answer (score 0):

With coq v8.4, you can set the environment variable `COQPATH` to a colon separated path (probably semi-colon separated on windows), and coq will treat those directories as if it was passed `-R <directory> ''`. In other words, it will recursively add all files, with a null prefix.

Also by default, coq v8.4 will automatically treat `~/.local/share/coq` (technically `${XDG_DATA_HOME}/coq`) the same way. Thus, you could just link the appropriate directories there, with the appropriate names (i.e. `Devel` and `CoLoR`).